# find outmost evaluation (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I have some Haskell code and need to write down **Leftmost-innermost** (call by value) and **outermost** (call-by-name):

```
second :: [Int] -> Int
second []           = 0
second (_:[])       = 0
second (_:x:xs)     = x

doubleEach :: [Int] -> [Int]
doubleEach []           = []
doubleEach (x:xs) = x * 2 : (doubleEach xs)

repeat :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
repeat x n = if n > 0 then x : (repeat x (n-1)) else []


repeat ( second (doubleEach [2,3,5] )) ( second [3, 1, 4] )
```

**innermost** (call-by-value):

```
1. repeat (second (doubleEach [2,3,5] )) (second [3,1,4])
2. repeat (second 4 : doubleEach [3,5])) (1)
3. repeat (second (4 : 6 : d [5])) (1)
4. repeat (second ( 4 : 6 : 10 )) (1)
5. repeat (6) (1)
6. [6]
```

**Question**: How can I get outermost (call-by-name) stept by step evaluation? I do not understand how I can do that if repeat needs specified values to work and they are not given until the inner part is not evaluated.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want, do you want to zip some strings? Please show us the full expected output.

Comment: Every program can be run in call-by-value and in call-by-name strategy. I do not understand how to write down the steps the program runs for call-by-name strategy. I hope it is more clear what I mean.

Comment: This isn't really Haskell. I'm not even sure it really belongs on Stackoverflow... Maybe cs.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get outermost (call-by-name) stept by step evaluation? I do not understand how I can do that if repeat needs specified values to work and they are not given until the inner part is not evaluated.

You don't need the values to expand the function call - you can just pass in the unevaluated expressions. And then you only evaluate those expressions when it's necessary for `if`s, pattern matches or primitive functions. That's how call-by-name evaluation works.

So your first step would be to take the body of `repeat`, replace each occurrence of `x` with `second (doubleEach [2,3,5])` and each occurrence of `n` with `second [3, 1, 4]`. Then you'll need to evaluate the `if` condition and then you proceed with the body of the `if`.